# Merging an Array of Arrays with a similar Array of Arrays with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, analytics

I am trying to merge two sets of analytical data from two different providers. The arrays, country name along with a metric, are arranged as follows:

```
[['Albania','1000'],['Australia','1000']]
```

Both data sets can contain different versions of the same country name (such as UK instead of United Kingdom). How can I go about merging these arrays of arrays in Javascript? By merge I mean combine the data sets for each country into a single set of arrays.

Example:

```
[['Albania','1000'],['United Kingdom','1000']]

+

[['Albania','1000'],['UK','1000']]

=

[['Albania','2000'],['United Kingdom','2000']]
```

**Clarifications:** Our mobile sites use one analytics provider where as our main global sites use another, different analytics provider. We need to merge these data sets to create an accurate report. There will only ever be 2 data sets needing to be merged.

Comment: What are the rules for "combining"? How do you know 'UK' and 'United Kingdom' should be combined?

Comment: Seems like this isn't the best data structure for your needs.

Comment: I would create set use cases, such as IF country EQUAL TO x THEN etc

Comment: Radu - this data structure is used as it is required to be in this format by the Google Visualisation API.

Comment: In your example, shouldn't the result be: `[['Albania','2000'],['United Kingdom','2000']]`

Comment: Try using an object literal instead of an array of arrays data type.

Comment: Another question, will there only ever be two arrays, or are you combining an arbitrary number of arrays?

Comment: There will only ever be 2 arrays. You were correct, my example contained an error.

Comment: [['Albania', '1000'],['Bananas','1000']] + [['Albania', '1000'],['Cream','1000']] + [['Albania', '1000'],['Smoothie','1000']] + [['Albania', '1000'],['United Kingdom','1000']] = [['Albania', '1000'],['United Kingdom','4000']]?

Comment: For future reference, I'm going to guess that you garnered a lot of downvotes since your conditions were not clear enough off the bat, and maybe because you didn't post what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a partial solution translated from the PHP post. This does not get you aliasing. The equivalent code in PHP looks a lot cleaner because of associative arrays. You could obtain a very nice solution if you had object literals instead of arrays to work with. This solution may require shims for [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and possibly [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) depending on your platform.

http://jsfiddle.net/radu/8JQBS/

```
var arr1 = [['Albania','1000'],['United Kingdom','1000']],
    arr2 = [['Albania','1000'],['UK','1000']],
    sum = [],
    index = -1;

var mergedArray = arr1.concat(arr2);

for (var i = 0, n = mergedArray.length; i !== n; i++) {

    for (var j = 0, m = sum.length; j !== m; j++) {   
        if (sum[j].indexOf(mergedArray[i][0]) !== -1) {
            index = j;
            break;            
        } else {
            index = -1;
        }
    }

    if (index !== -1) {
        sum[index][1] = (
            parseInt(sum[index][1], 10) +  
            parseInt(mergedArray[i][1], 10)
        ).toString();
    } else {
        sum.push([mergedArray[i][0], mergedArray[i][1]]);
    }
}
```

This produces: `[['Albania', '2000'], ['United Kingdom', '1000'], ['UK', '1000']]`. You could implement aliasing for this, but it's annoying - see below for a better solution.

Here is another solution which instead of producing an array of arrays as a result, gives an object literal. In my opinion this is much better. You may not be able to control the data you get from whatever API you're using, but you can control how you process it, and this should make downstream code better. This may require a shim for [`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty).

http://jsfiddle.net/radu/fPsdc/

```
var arr1 = [['Albania','1000'],['United Kingdom','1000']],
    arr2 = [['Albania','1000'],['UK','1000']], 
    mergedArray = arr1.concat(arr2),
    sum = {},

    // property is preferred name
    // define aliases in lowercase
    aliases = {
        'uk' : 'United Kingdom'
    };

for (var i = 0, n = mergedArray.length; i !== n; i++) {
    var country = mergedArray[i][0],
        num = parseInt(mergedArray[i][1], 10);

    if (aliases.hasOwnProperty(country.toLowerCase())) {
        country = aliases[country.toLowerCase()];          
    }

    if (sum.hasOwnProperty(country))
        sum[country] += num;        
    else
        sum[country] = num;
}
```

This produces: `{'Albania' : 2000, 'United Kingdom' : 2000}`. If you *really* must have an array of arrays as a result.. you can do this:

```
var arrSum = [];

for (var prop in sum) {
    if (sum.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        arrSum.push([prop, sum[prop]]);
    }        
}
```

Comment: No, there is only ever 2 different data sets of which each country will only be defined once within.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create an array that maps all possible names of a country to a single value.

Then you can use array_merge() and parse the values, placing them in a results array.

E.G:

```
<?php
$countryMap = array(
    'United Kingdom'           => 'uk',
    'UK'                       => 'uk',
    'Albania'                  => 'alb'
);

$array1 = array(array('Albania', 1000), array('United Kingdom', 1000));
$array2 = array(array('Albania', 1000), array('UK', 1000));

$mergedArray = array_merge($array1, $array2);

$finalArray = array();

foreach ($mergedArray as $a) {
    if (isset($finalArray[$countryMap[$a[0]]]))
        $finalArray[$countryMap[$a[0]]] += $a[1];
    else
        $finalArray[$countryMap[$a[0]]] = $a[1];
}

var_dump($finalArray);
```

Comment: Answer calls for javascript..

Comment: I would +1 if the asker's requirements was for a php solution. At this point, I have no idea what the asker's requirements are. Good answer though, clean and scalable.

Comment: @HansZ Have you read the question title?

Comment: My mistake. I was browsing php all morning and thought I was still in that section. Was the downvote really necessary though?

Comment: @Matt Thank you for the answer, but the solution must be in Javascript.

Comment: @RyanBrodie you had a php tag before I deleted it, leading to me assume either you wanted a php solution as well as a javascript without being explicit, or you put php in by accident.

Comment: I did this to increase question exposure.

Comment: @Ryan you can convert this code to javascript fairly easily, but there's no array_merge() function that I know of. Simply run the foreach loop on each array. You'll get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide a third array that defines all of the aliases for a given country. Maybe something like:

```
// the preferred alias is the first element of each set
var countryAliases = [
    [ 'United Kingdom', 'UK' ],
    [ 'United States', 'US'],
    // ...
];
```

Simply loop through each data array, find each item's country in the alias map, and then write the result to a single result array, using the preferred alias as the key.